# Adding a new conditional column to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr, tidyverse

I wonder if the following is possible in R?

I want to add a new column to my `Data` called `task` whose values are to be determined
by the following statements:

- IF `order` is `"sc"`, `task` value for rows with odd-numbered `time` values (*1,3,...*) is `"simple"` otherwise `"complex"`.
- IF `order` is `"cs"`, `task` value for rows with odd-numbered `time` values (*1,3,...*) is `"complex"` otherwise `"simple"`.

```r
Data = read.table(text="
id order  time task
1  sc     1    x
1  sc     2    x
2  cs     1    x
2  cs     2    x
3  sc     1    x
3  sc     2    x
4  cs     1    x
4  cs     2    x
", h= TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` and `time %% 2` to determine odd or even.

```r
Data |>
  transform(task = ifelse(order == 'sc' & time %% 2 == 1 |
                          order == 'cs' & time %% 2 == 0,
                          'simple', 'complex'))

  id order time    task
1  1    sc    1  simple
2  1    sc    2 complex
3  2    cs    1 complex
4  2    cs    2  simple
5  3    sc    1  simple
6  3    sc    2 complex
7  4    cs    1 complex
8  4    cs    2  simple
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer by Darren Tsai is great! I'm not sure what the speed of `ifelse()` is like, I don't have much experience using it, but here's an alternate option:

All it does is get the row numbers (via `which()`) that match the conditions for the `"simple"` case and then again for `"complex"` case.

```
index.simple <- which( (Data$order=="sc" & Data$time%%2==1) | (Data$order=="cs" & Data$time%%2==0) )
Data$task[index.simple]  <- "simple" 

index.complex <- which( (Data$order=="sc" & Data$time%%2==0) | (Data$order=="cs" & Data$time%%2==1) )                     
Data$task[index.complex]  <- "complex"
```